# Is it a sin to vacuum cobwebs & ants while cleaning?

Tags: personal-practice, karma, lay-practices

I vacuum away cobwebs, ants & any other small insects I find while cleaning the house. My intention is to clean the house but I still feel bad about those insects.  And most of the time I don't clean the vacuum cleaner bag on the same day & even if I do so some insects are already dead. I'm unable to use brooms or anything to clean the cobwebs due to medical conditions. Is it a sin to do so?

Comment: Maybe try those soft-feather dusters and wearing a mask if you have allergy? They don't kick up as much dirt as the electric vacuum, save you some electric bills, and they also save the lives of those tiny poor beings. Give it a try. Less effort and more benefits!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. :)

Comment: The fact that you feel uneasy and ask this question indicates that you know the answer. Which method of cleaning would a spider prefer you to use? Perhaps you could compromise by gently sweeping the cobwebs away from the spider's hiding place and then vacuuming the brush. The trouble with vacuums is they suck the insects out of their nooks and crannies in a way a brush does not, .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buddhism doesn’t deal with sins, it deals with consequences of our actions (karma).

Your example seems like a trade off between feeling bad for the insects on one hand, and having a dirty home on the other. The former, being merciful towards other living beings (karuna) is considered a virtue in Buddhism as it can save us from feeling bad.

Sometimes life is about choosing the option giving us the least bad consequences for everyone involved, out of all the options. The effort to balance our actions (upekkha) is considered yet another virtue in Buddhism as it unifies others wellbeing with our own, saving us from destructive self-sacrifice on one hand and selfishness on the other.